# How can I use the property of a label in a subview for swift

Tags: ios, swift

I add a view and its class is "MyView.swift".
then I add a label and register its property to "ViewController.swift"

```
@IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
```

I want to revise lbl.text in "MyView.swift", how can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean you want to revise?

Comment: just change its text content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your question: You have view controller. On the UIViewController's view you have another view MyView, and on this view you have a label and you want to change its text.

In this case it's better to change the text of the label in view controller `lbl.text = "new text"`

But if you can't do this I see several solutions:

1) You can set `lbl.tag = 2016` and after that you can get the label from the view:

```
if let myLabel = self.viewWithTag(2016) as? UILabel {
        myLabel.text = "new text"
    }
```

I think it's the best way.

2) You can send NSNotification from the view and receive this notification in the ViewController and change text in the view controller

3) You can have a weak reference in your view to ViewController and a method in your ViewController to change text. In this case in `viewDidLoad` you can set this reference  `myView.viewController = self`. And then in your MyView you can call this method `viewController.changeTextTo("new text")`

Comment: but the lbl declared in "ViewController.swift", can "self" be used in "MyView.swift" to get lbl?

Comment: the second method works fine!

Comment: the third method generates a error: "Type "MyView" has no member "viewController""

Comment: 1) "but the lbl declared in "ViewController.swift", can "self" be used in "MyView.swift" to get lbl?" You can use it with or without self, it doesn't matter, but the point is We don't care that it was declared in ViewController, because this label in subview of MyView, we can use the method viewWithTag 3) "the third method generates a error: "Type "MyView" has no member "viewController"" Of course, you need to declare this weak property in MyView class